# condition_variable's speed to acquire lock is low

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, condition-variable

This problem is about `condition_variable.wait()` function. I figure that it is probably not locking the `unique_lock` immediately when it is notified. Let me show my code and you would better understand my test.

Note: compiler g++, std=c++14

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

mutex global_mut;
condition_variable global_cond;
atomic<bool> bval;
atomic<int> ival;

void accLock() {
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(global_mut);
  while (!bval.load()) {
    global_cond.wait(lock);
  }
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " get the lock" << endl;
  ival.store(2, memory_order_release);
  lock.unlock();
}

void getVal() {
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(global_mut);
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " get the lock with " << ival.load(memory_order_acquire) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  bval.store(false);
  ival.store(0, memory_order_release);

  // now my global_cond should be waiting for being notified
  std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, accLock);

  // now my global_cond should be awaken and lock global_mut  
  bval.store(true);
  global_cond.notify_one();

  // getVal should be waiting for global_mut to be unlocked
  getVal();
  return 0;
}
```

Idealy, I want my `accLock` thread to lock the mutex first and change `ival`, in such way that getVal() could load the latest `ival`, which is 2. I expect to see output like

```cpp
void accLock() get the lock
void getVal() get the lock with 2
```

But in reality, this out is

```cpp
void getVal() get the lock with 0
void accLock() get the lock
```

Obviously, this `unique_lock` didn't lock "immediately" in `global_cond`, letting the `lock_guard` in `getVal()` get the mutex first.
May I ask what is the correct way to implement what I want? Do I understand correctly about `condition_variable`? Thanks.

NOTE:
I use memory_order_acl and release because I thought this could help me 'correct' the order. But it not works tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two threads contend for a mutex, it's arbitrary which one will get it. If you want one thing to happen before something else happens, it's your obligation to write code to make that happen. A mutex won't enforce any particular ordering.

If you don't want the `getVal` to run until the other thread finishes, you have write some code to wait for it to finish. You can use the mutex and condition variable to do this, but you didn't.

Generally speaking, the implementation tries to be as efficient as possible subject to the constraints you impose on it. Stopping the thread that calls `getVal` is inefficient (since all its code is hot in the cache and it's already been scheduled), so the implementation doesn't do it.

The implementation has no way to know what you want and it wouldn't make sense for it to do things inefficiently in the hopes that maybe that's what you really wanted but didn't tell it.

Note that you might get a different result in a later run. The order in which ready-to-run threads execute is unpredictable unless you make it predictable. Both 
threads are ready-to-run, so you can't expect any particular reliable ordering. It will be whatever the implementation thinks is best under the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for resp. I thought mutex should be following "first come first use" policy, isn't it? In my code above, could I say the "CPU" only think "oh okay I would grant this mutex to getVal() because I am working in the same thread, no need to switch context".

Comment: if say I add `this_thread::sleep(0.1 seconds)` between `notify_one()` and `getVal()` then I could the expected result. That's why I thought condition_variable's way to lock the mutex is slow.

Comment: First come first use tends to be very, very inefficient. The thread that comes last typically has all its code and data hot in the caches. So you are asking for an implementation to maximize inefficiency. That would be an insane implementation decision. (And it would still be unreliable. Your code never makes sure the thread that calls `accLock` even tries to get the lock at all. The whole process could return from `main` and terminate before that even happens.)

Comment: @milanow The sleep changes what is most efficient. Why make the `accLock` thread wait when it can make forward progress? The implementation does what it thinks is efficient, which can vary based on all kinds of things. YOU CANNOT RELY ON IT TO DO WHAT YOU THINK IT WILL DO! You must write code to enforce any ordering you wish to rely on. The implementation tries to make as much forward progress as quickly as possible. You have to write code to ensure the forward progress that the implementation chooses is what you want.)

Comment: I have undersrtood that another cond_variable could finish the job/ Then how about using memory_order_acq_rel? It does force a W-R order write? No matter who acquire the lock

Comment: That not what memory ordering does. It doesn't make anything wait for anything else. It just ensures (oversimplifying significantly) that one thread sees the result of another thread's operations in the order they appear in that other thread's code.

Comment: So, for example, if thread A does `a=1; b=2;` memory ordering can ensure that another thread that does something like `if (b==2) return a;` will get `1` since it will see the writes in the order they occurred. It doesn't make the thread wait -- it might not see `b` as 2.

Comment: Super thanks! Misunderstand atomic because I am kinda lost when reading <Concurrency in Action> Chap5 about memory model in c++. Back to this question, I guess a better way is to use another condition_variable. Has marked as the solution.